# Feature: Include option for more Page buttons in the search results

Tags: feature-request, search, user-interface

In the search page, we often get many pages. For example, I want to go through the non-answered questions in the SDEs

> https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stochastic-differential-equations?sort=Newest&filters=NoAnswers&uqlId=1638&page=6&pagesize=50

but it has twelve pages

[image]

many of which are hidden by dots. One could simply change the url from "page=6" to say "page 10", but I think the user will benefit by having more choices on how to move

- when trying to answer multiple questions from a given tag
- studying some concept/type of question from a long list of results

So the request is to include the option to have more pages (that way if a user is on their desktop, they can just click on "All Pages" to see all the buttons).

Comment: I'm not sure that this is necessary.  You can change the URL easily enough, and adding more buttons to search is going to cause problems on smaller displays (e.g. phones).

Comment: I modified my request to give the option to the user of having "all pages".

Comment: Related on Meta SE: [For paginated results, add a way to type the page number to which to navigate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385699). This feature request, and variations of it, have been suggested several times (see the comments under the linked question for examples), but it doesn't seem to have received much attention.

Comment: thank you. This is a small feature and so it is hard to gather many votes for it.